# Filter pandas data according to the equation

Tags: python, pandas

Hello everyone i have such a problem. I need to filter my data accorging to equation.
What do i mean

For example i have such dataframe:

```
    tonnage period_year
5   2,462,297.5 2014
13  2,274,912.9 2015
19  2,181,492.2 2015
20  2,173,654.8 2016
21  2,158,043.7 2016
... ... ...
92885   5.0 2016
92886   5.0 2016
92901   5.0 2016
94814   0.0 2016
94861   0.0 2013
```

and i have

```py
data[data.tonnage > 0.02e6]['tonnage'].sum()/data.tonnage.sum() * 100.0
```

97.08690080799717

```py
data[data.tonnage > 5e6]['tonnage'].sum()/data.tonnage.sum() * 100.0
```

18.541547916532426

so i need to find the max x  where

```py
data[data.tonnage > x]['tonnage'].sum()/data.tonnage.sum() * 100.0
```

will gave answer equal or greater than 40

what's the best way to do it?

Comment: @jezrael  ```!!!!!!MAXIMUM X!!!!!!!``` - this x, for example 350000, where the equation ```df[df.tonnage > !!!!!!MAXIMUM X!!!!!!!].sum()/df.tonnage.sum() * 100 >= 40``` is true

Comment: @jezrael for example i have tonnages ```tonnages = [100,100,100,200,5,5,5,5,5]``` and the ```max x``` for this equation will be 5, so i just need to filter small data

Comment: Not understand, can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like `tonnages = [100,100,100,200,5,5,5,5,5]` ?

Comment: `df.loc[df.tonnage > df.tonnage.mode()[0]]`?

Comment: @jezrael using this equation i need to filter small data, but i automatic calculation for filter rate where the sum of my data is greater than 40%

Comment: @jezrael i correct my question

Comment: Still not clear! What you mean by "will gave answer equal or greater than 40" ? Is that it will show up at least a single row ?

Comment: Must `x` be a value inside the `tonnage` column?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
# Your sample input
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'tonnage': [100,100,100,200,5,5,5,5,5]
})

# Get the sum of each unique value in `tonnage`
t = df.groupby('tonnage')['tonnage'].sum().sort_index(ascending=False)

# Since your requirement is "> x", we have to subtract the current value from the cumsum
ratio = (t.cumsum() - t) / t.sum() * 100

# And voila!
x = ratio[ratio >= 40].index[0]
```